# How to remove the quotes from a date in querystring (angularjs)?

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, url

I'm using angularjs for my sharepoint project. I have an anchor tag which contains the href which holds a url. The format is as given below.

```
<li><a href="/SitePages/MetaSearchResults.aspx?Type=PublishDate&Value={{item.PublishDate }}">{{item.PublishDate | date:'dd MMMM yyyy'}}</a></li>
```

I'm getting the Value as `"2014-03-25T18:30:00.000Z"` including the double quotes. Is there anyway to remove the double quotes from this querystring ?

Comment: You try do this in a list form?

Comment: No. I'm creating an aspx page. In this page, I'm trying to create a list of items using ng-repeat. Each item contains a url.